# Searching for URLs with subdomains using grep

Tags: grep, regular-expression, string, search

I have a file with content similar to:

```
mail.google.com
srv1.mail.google.com
google.com
facebook.com
yahoo.com
tt.twitter.com
```

I want to search for lines with subdomains. I used this command:

```
grep -e '(.\.)*.\..$' test.txt
```

The command details:

- `(.\.)*` : for any characters followed by dot one or more times.
- `.\..$` : anycharacter followed by dot, then any character

Examples of the string patterns I expect to find:

```
mail.google.com
srv1.mail.google.com
```

but it does not find anything. The output I am looking for should be lines with subdomains:

```
mail.google.com
srv1.mail.google.com
tt.twitter.com
```

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```sh
grep -E '(.+\.)+.+\..+$' test.txt
```

Output:

```
mail.google.com
srv1.mail.google.com
tt.twitter.com
```

Details:

- `(.+\.)+` - any characters followed by dot, search for this grouping one or more times.
- `.+\.` - any character one or more times followed by a single period.
- `.+$` - any character one or more times, followed by an end-of-line.

The problem with your regular expression is/are:

- `(.\.)*` - matches any character, and then a period. But the `*` may match zero or more times. You probably want `+`.
- `.\.` - matches exactly **one** character, then a period. You want a `+` after the first `.` (`.+`) to match one or more characters.
- `.$` - matches exactly **one** character, then an end of line. You want a `+` after the `.` (`.+`) to match one or more characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with simplifying the criteria to "lines that have at least two periods", you could use a simple grep:

```
grep -E '\.[^.]+\.' < file
```

This enables extended regular expressions then looks for a period followed by one-or-more non-periods followed by a period. You could tighten it down further by requiring some number of characters to appear on either side of the periods:

```
grep -E '.\.[^.]+\..' < file
```

The above would avoid false-positive hits on input like:

```
foo.com.
```

or
    .com.

Based on [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21872376/4957508) from 2014, a TLD cannot be all numeric, but could (in theory) be a single character, so you could use:

```
grep -E '\.[^.]+\.[[:alpha:]]'
```